# Create "literal" component in SFC won't work?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a dead simple "literal" component(`MyComponent` in this example) inside a SFC(vue 3):

```
<template>
  <MyComponent>aha</MyComponent>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";

const MyComponent = {
  name: "MyCompoent",
  template: "<h1>aha</h1>",
};

export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
};
</script>
```

But this won't work...

However, if I split the `MyComponent` into another SFC, it will work.

Anyone knows why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `template` option is ignored because the runtime compiler is disabled by default as an optimization. Using that option would cause a console warning like this:

```
[Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js".
```

In Vue CLI generated projects, set the [`runtimeCompiler` flag](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) to enable the `template` option:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```